# Nodejs still routing to a deleted entry in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I used the following code to delete an entry in mongodb

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res) {
    Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, student) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect('/students/' + req.params.id);
        }
        console.log('Deleted student.');
        console.log(student);
        res.redirect('/students');
    });
});
```

The delete goes through, as I no longer see it in the database; however, if I visit the old page /students/:id it goes through instead of redirecting back and I receive an error because I'm attempting to use methods on null object.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    Student.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundStudent) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect('/students');
        }
        res.render('pages/students/show', { student : foundStudent });
    });
});
```

How can I get it to know that that id no longer exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

send to show only if student is found. according to your logic if there is no error it will got to 'show' as not found is not error so it will goto show.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    Student.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundStudent) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect('/students');
        }

        if(foundStudent){
        res.render('pages/students/show', { student : foundStudent });
        }

           return res.redirect('/students');
    });
});
```

Comment: wow silly mistake.. just curious but why is it that if I enter a previous id into /students/:id it goes through but if I just try something random like asdfashd it doesnt?

Comment: asdfashd is not valid monodb id. mongodb id's are combination of timestamp and other elements. maybe mongodb validates an id before passing it.